# Select Multiple Images from gallery and convert each image to Base64

Tags: android

This is my code in which it selects one image at a time and coverts it into base64 but I want to choose multiple file/ images from android gallery and then it converts each file/image into base64. I am stuck here. Please help me out.

Below is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button selectPDF;
    private int REQUESTCODE_PICK_Image=100;
    static String fileName;
    Uri seletedURI;
    int count;
    static TextView tv;
    static TextView tv1;
    static String extension = "";
    private static ArrayList<String> galleryImageUrls;
    ImageView img1[];
    Bitmap yourbitmap, resized;
    String imageEncoded;
    List<String> imagesEncodedList;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.convertedText);
        tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.nameOfFile);


        selectPDF=(Button)findViewById(R.id.selectPDF);
        selectPDF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                chooseFile();

            }
        });

    }

    private void chooseFile() {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            try {
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUESTCODE_PICK_Image);

            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static String convertFileToByteArray() {
        byte[] byteArray = null;
        File filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        Log.v("New file Path",filePath.toString());
        String filename=fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
        Log.v("File Name",filename);


        int i = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
        if (i >= 0) {
            extension = fileName.substring(i+1);
            Log.v("extension",extension);
        }

        File file = new File(fileName);
        //Log.v("Full Path",file.toString());
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] b = new byte[1024 * 11];
            int bytesRead = 0;

            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(b)) != -1) {
                bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            byteArray = bos.toByteArray();

            Log.e("Byte array", ">" + byteArray);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String convertFile= Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        tv.setText(convertFile);
        Log.v("File Information",convertFile);
        return String.valueOf(0);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == REQUESTCODE_PICK_Image && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                // Get the Image from data

                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                imagesEncodedList = new ArrayList<String>();
                if(data.getData()!=null){

                    seletedURI=data.getData();
                    if (seletedURI.toString().startsWith("file:")) {
                        fileName = seletedURI.getPath();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                        ClipData mClipData = data.getClipData();
                        ArrayList<Uri> mArrayUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < mClipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                            ClipData.Item item = mClipData.getItemAt(i);
                            Uri uri = item.getUri();
                                mArrayUri.add(uri);

                            // Get the cursor
                            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                            // Move to first row
                            cursor.moveToFirst();

                            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                            fileName  = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                            imagesEncodedList.add(fileName);
                            cursor.close();

                        }
                        Log.v("LOG_TAG", "Selected Images " + mArrayUri.size());
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

        /*//..............converting files into base64.......*/

        convertFileToByteArray();
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there anyone..??

Comment: Please explain better your problem, what is the part that's not working, getting multiple images, converting em as base64?

Comment: this code is selects only one file at a time and then it convert it to base 64. Now i want when i select multiple file it will also convert all the selected file into base 64

Comment: The code already selects multiple images, it depends on the app you choose to do it, try picking google photos app in the chooser

Comment: yes its works on google photos but not from gallery/ Explorer and one more issue that when we select it from google photo, the last item that i select is converting into base64 not the whole image which i selects